# Strapi relation in quiz

Tags: javascript, node.js, content-management-system, strapi, headless-cms

I'm new to Strapi, and the first project that I want to use it for is a quiz web app.
I made 2 collection types: Question, and Quiz.
They have a "Quiz has many Questions" relation.

The problem is that when someone makes a new quiz, he has to go to the collection of the questions and make questions that he can add to the quiz. However, I would like to have the ability to add the questions directly inside the quiz collection.

Is there any way to achieve this, or can I create my own react components to make it myself, and then store it in JSON format?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the API directly.
You can build a React App and from there make a Page, called create quiz.
You can than add a quiz and the questions to that with the API.

https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/developer-resources/content-api/content-api.html#api-endpoints

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I will try it out, and get back to you after it.

Comment: This works fine, but is it possible to keep everything inside the strapi cms, or are there other cms's that provide this functionality?

Comment: Strapi is only a headless CMS - you cant provide much user interface on it. If you think this should be a generic feature, you could formalise it and throw it up on GitHub as a feature request. If the community approves, i would love to give the implementation a shot.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create it in strapi itself you will have to create a custom plugin.
Kindly refer [custom plugin](https://strapi.io/blog/how-to-create-an-import-content-plugin-part-1-4)